# What phase does stopPropagation effect?

Tags: javascript

According to quirksmode, modern browsers have a capturing phase and a bubbling phase.  See [here.](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html)

If I use [stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation) in my event handler ( set to either phase by the Boolean argument ) how will it function?

Will it work both ways?  That is if I set it to capture mode, will it also prevent the bubbling phase.  And vice-versa as well.

Here is the W3 reference ( [stopPropagation](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-event-type-stopPropagation) ).

I'm troubleshooting an event handler, and need to understand exactly how `stopPropagation()` functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stopping propagation during the capture phase will prevent further handlers from running, including handlers registered with the bubbling phase.

The [W3C documentation on event flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow) says (emphasis mine):

> This specification defines three event phases: *capture phase*; *target
>   phase*; and *bubble phase*. Event objects complete these phases in the
>   specified order using the partial propagation paths as defined below.
>   **A phase must be skipped if it is not supported, or if the event
>   object's propagation has been stopped.** For example, if the
>   `Event.bubbles` attribute is set to false, the bubble phase will be
>   skipped, and **if `Event.stopPropagation()` has been called prior to the
>   dispatch, all phases must be skipped**.